# How to reduce the height of the picker

Tags: ios, css, titanium, titanium-alloy, picker

I have created a Picker, but I am unable to reduce the height of the picker. I tried the height property too still no use.

My code:

```
<View class="pageContainer">
        <Picker id="langPicker">
            <PickerRow title="Select a Language"/>
            <PickerRow title="English"/>
            <PickerRow title="French"/>
            <PickerRow title="Spanish"/>
        </Picker>
<Button class="button" onClick="saveLang" dataTransform="transformFunction">Proceed</Button>
</View>
```

**Style**

```
"#langPicker": {
    width: '90%',
    top: '25dp',
    height: '50dp'
}
```

How can I reduce the height of the picker? Any suggestions

Comment: Maybe you can wrap your picker in a view and use the height function of the view. Set the height of the picker to fill the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Picker):

> "On iOS, by default, the size of the picker, including its background,
>   is fixed at the same size as the iPhone keyboard to respect the iOS
>   Human Interface Guidelines. The size of the picker should not be
>   modified."

So even if you do somehow manage to hack the height of the picker on iOS, it will most likely be rejected from the app store when you try to submit.

Workaround for this is to show the picker only when the users presses something on the view.

Comment: Yes, I completely agree you. we can show the picker on click of any view. But how can we minimize after selecting the value in picker. Can  you suggest some idea

Comment: one way is to hide the picker off the screen by giving it a negative bottom, then animate it up